# Tensorflow reshape issue, ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 2) for Tensor u'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 1, 2)'

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I get this error message: 
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 2) for Tensor u'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 1, 2)'

My training and test data have 2 features

```
[[10, 10],[1,2],[3,2]...]
```

and my target data are like this:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0]...]
```

Here is my code:

```
training_data = np.vstack(training_data)
training_target = np.vstack(training_target)
test_data = np.vstack(test_data)
test_target = np.vstack(test_target)

learning_rate = 0.001

n_input = 2  
n_steps = 1  
n_hidden = 128  
n_classes = 2  

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_steps, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

# Define weights
weights = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

def RNN(x, weights, biases):
    x = tf.unstack(x, n_steps, 1)

    # Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
    lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)

    # Get lstm cell output
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Linear activation, using rnn inner loop last output
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']

pred = RNN(x, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Evaluate model
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    step = 1

    for i in range(len(training_data)):
        batch_x = training_data[i]
        batch_y = training_target[i]
        print(batch_x)
        print(batch_y)
        batch_x = tf.reshape(batch_x, [1, 2]).eval()
        print(batch_x)
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        print("Iter " + str(step) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + "{:.5f}".format(acc))

    print("Optimization Finished!")

    print("Testing Accuracy:", sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: test_data, y: test_target}))
```

I need help with reshaping, I didn't implement yet next batch function, just trying to get this working.

Didn't include a part where I am loading CSV files,... etc.

Any comment on the code is great, thank you.

Comment: Multiple things I see here. Your batch_x is a numpy array so you should use np.reshape rather than tf.reshape (at least for clarity, assuming it does the right thing). Most importantly, your batch_x first dimension should be the size of your batch (corresponding to ? or None dimension in the placeholder). For instance if you feed batches of size 10, then batch_x should have the shape (10, 1, 2) and it will have no problem feeding it in a (?, 1, 2) tensor. Anther thing, if you want to get the result from two ops corresponding to the same run, use: acc, loss = session.run([accuracy, loss])

Comment: @AlWld Hi, thank you for the comment, still not sure that understand you, my batch_x is [ 13.89000034   8.32999992], I iterate just one batch per loop, so it should be like this: batch_x = np.reshape(batch_x, (1, 1, 2)), but still doesn't work for me. What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: It should be: batch_x = np.reshape(batch_x, [1, 1, 2]) and then sess.run([accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x}). However your code and the error message suppose that you are doing batch_x = np.reshape(batch_x, [1, 2]). Could you please double check that? Thanks

Comment: @AlWld Hi, so I have this now,              
                batch_x = np.reshape(batch_x, [1, 1, 2])
                sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y}) other part below with accuracy is commented, it throws me now: 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 961, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2,) for Tensor u'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 2)', really strange, not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Good you solved the problem. This one is for the labels, so batch_y = np.reshape(batch_y, [1, 2]) and you should be good to go. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @AlWld You didn't understand me, I didn't solve it :)

Comment: see my complete answer

Comment: @AlWld Thank you, an issue was in reshaping both batches, X and Y.

Comment: If that solves your problem can you please mark my answer as the good one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to feed arrays who do not respect the placeholders dimensions. E.g. for batch_x you try to feed [1, 2] into [?, 1, 2] and for batch_y you try to feed [2] into [?, 2]. You want to feed [1, 1, 2] into [?, 1, 2] and [1, 2] into [?, 2] for batch_x and batch_y respectively if your batch_size is 1.

```
batch_size = 1
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    step = 1

    for i in range(len(training_data)):
        batch_x = training_data[i]
        batch_y = training_target[i]
        batch_x = np.reshape(batch_x, [batch_size, 1, 2])
        batch_y = np.reshape(batch_y, [batch_size, 2])
        [_, acc, loss] = sess.run([optimizer, accuracy, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        print("Iter " + str(step) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + "{:.5f}".format(acc))
```